# Not sure why I can't indent this code in Python

Tags: python

If I run the following code while NOT indenting the print and input lines, my code works. Here is an example of code that works

```
def add(a, b):

    try:
        return float(a) + float(b)

    except ValueError:
        return print('Not a number')

print ("The first number you want to add?")
a = input("First no: ")
print ("What's the second number you want to add?")
b = input("Second no: ")

result = add(a, b)

print(result)
```

---

However if I indent the input and print lines I get a message that A is not defined

```
def add(a, b):

    try:
        return float(a) + float(b)

    except ValueError:
        return print('Not a number')

    print ("The first number you want to add?")
    a = input("First no: ")
    print ("What's the second number you want to add?")
    b = input("Second no: ")

result = add(a, b)

print(result)





Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jlangdon/PycharmProjects/untitled/Stuff.py", line 16, in     <module>
result = add(a, b)
NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

.............Why can't I indent print and input? Thanks

Comment: What value do you expect a and b to be when you call add(a, b) ?

Comment: "Scope". The variable `a` only "exists" inside the function.

Comment: The indentation is not the problem, the variable scope is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because `a` and `b` are defined inside the `result` function when you don't indent. which will only have to be seen as a variable defined only when the program run inside the function `result`, but result requires two parameters a and b which should be defined outside the function as `main` variable not inside. thats why the

> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >
> > > File "/Users/jlangdon/PycharmProjects/untitled/Stuff.py", line 16, in
> > >
> > > result = add(a, b)
> > >
> > > NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Because the `a` and `b` in `result = add(a, b)` are not defined. You need to provide actual values to that function.

Example:

```
def add(a,b):

    try:
        return float(a) + float(b)

    except ValueError:
        print('Not a number')

    print ("The first number you want to add?")
    a = input("First no: ")
    print ("What's the second number you want to add?")
    b = input("Second no: ")

result = add(12.3,45.6)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't indent then:

```
a = input("First no: ")
```

Creates `a`, and:

```
b = input("Second no: ")
```

Creates `b`

If you indent `a` and `b` are not created, and here:

```
result = add(a, b)
```

You have an error.

Answer (score 1):

That's because... `a` is not defined. How could it be? The first thing your code *does* is:

```
result = add(a,b)
```

But `a` has no value, nor does `b`. `add` never even gets called.